# Unmounting and Mounting Drives

Tags: mount, unmount

I have a passport device that I plugged in using firewire that I use to house old , unused files so that my Mac computer would process more freely.  After I connect it the drive is read, I then move files over with no problem.  So that works done! Because I dont see where I can force a password when opening the Passport device (and I have some important files on it) I decided to unmount it. Once I unmount it I no longer see the drive. To see the drive again, do I have to unplug the firewire and replug it in or is there another way without me having to do that tedious task again and again?

Answer (score 2):

Try "**Disks**" application in Ubuntu for mount again without reconnecting.

Click on the play/stop button for mount/unmount the drive.
[image: Disk mounted in ubuntu]

[image: Disk Unmounted in Ubuntu]

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you unmounting it?
I ask this b/c if you're unmounting the drive by clicking the little arrow next to its name in your file manager, this actually is ejecting it.

(Alot of people get confused b/w the `umount`command and the `eject` command. `eject`completely removes the media, whilst `umount`unmounts it, but still leaves the media connected in the background)

The simple solution is to stop using that little arrow in your file manager. Instead right click on the drive name & choose the 'Unmount' option. However if you do accidentally eject it, heres a work around to stop having to reinsert the media again.

Open up the terminal & type `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id`

From here, you need to check what device node the drive in question is linked to (if you have no other removable media connected it will probably be ../../sdb. This equates to /dev/sdb)

Then its a case of doing `sudo eject -t /dev/sdb` *(substitute /dev/sdb with what you got above)*.

Its funny b/c the -t flag of the eject command is actually to close a CD-ROM tray, but it also seems to fool the system into thinking you've reinserted an external drive.

`